# Python - reading CSV and using dictionary values

Tags: python, csv

Using python, I've started out with:

```
import csv

openingStatement = {1: "this is the BEST generic opening!", 2: "this is a GOOD generic opening",
                    3: "this is an OKAY generic opening",
                    4: "this is NOT GOOD, something is going on to deserve this opening"}

with open("/Users/DaveVavala/Desktop/Practice Automated Report.csv", 'r', newline='') as mainFile:
    reader = csv.reader(mainFile, delimiter=",")
    header = next(reader)

    for row in reader:
        studentName = row[0]

        opening = row[1]

        qualities = row[2]

        print(studentName + opening)
```

My csv file is simply:

```
Name,Opening,Qualities
Anna,1,1
Billy,1,2
Corban,2,3
Diane,3,2
Eru,1,2
```

My goal is to get the appropriate line from the openingStatement dictionary connected to each corresponding student. For example, when I print I'll end up with "Anna this is the BEST generic opening!", for my first line and then all the other names afterwards. What should my print line be besides print(studentName...?

Trying to find answers but most sites focus on reading from dictionaries IN a csv file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the get() dictionary method to provide a default string for when the key isn't in the dictionary:

```
print(studentName + openingStatement.get(opening, 
       "That's no opening at all, I am afraid!"))
```

Comment: Good to know. Is there a way openingStatement.get to find the key in the csv file?